# Python: BeautifulSoup missing the tags

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have written a python program which lists all the subreddits present on this [page](https://www.reddit.com/subreddits). I am using BeautifulSoup(BS). It's working fine. Problem is that BS is missing all the nsfw subs in the page.

My program outputs

```
http://www.reddit.com/subreddits
http://www.reddit.com/r/funny/
http://www.reddit.com/r/pics/
http://www.reddit.com/r/AdviceAnimals/
http://www.reddit.com/r/todayilearned/
http://www.reddit.com/r/gifs/
http://www.reddit.com/r/BlackPeopleTwitter/
http://www.reddit.com/r/videos/
http://www.reddit.com/r/WTF/
http://www.reddit.com/r/aww/
http://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/
http://www.reddit.com/r/gaming/
http://www.reddit.com/r/leagueoflegends/
http://www.reddit.com/r/worldnews/
http://www.reddit.com/r/me_irl/
http://www.reddit.com/r/news/
http://www.reddit.com/r/pcmasterrace/
http://www.reddit.com/r/politics/
http://www.reddit.com/r/4chan/
http://www.reddit.com/r/trees/
http://www.reddit.com/r/TrollXChromosomes/
http://www.reddit.com/r/space/
http://www.reddit.com/r/Showerthoughts/
http://www.reddit.com/r/mildlyinteresting/
http://www.reddit.com/r/GlobalOffensive/
http://www.reddit.com/r/movies/
```

which is in complete sync with the actual sub-reddit list. So I want to know why is it that it is missing nsfw subs. When I saw the source code of the page, there was nothing different from other sfw subs. Thanks.

If any other info is required, please ask.

Thanks

Edit: turns out, when I made a request to reddit, It was without any cookies. By default you are shown SFW sub-reddits by reddit.com. For simulating the browser experience in python, you have to use the cookies of the browser.

Comment: please post your code;  how would we know otherwise?

Comment: I don't even see any NSFW subreddits..

Comment: that's because by default, reddit don't show you nsfw subs. try opening any nsfw sub and it will ask you for over-18 permission. After that try accessing subreddit page and you will see nsfw subs.